# WPF (system)sounds don't work

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, system-sounds

I have the following problem: I just want to play a short sound but I hear nothing.
The soundfile's property "Copy to output directory" says "Copy always".
Strangely when I copy a existing and working example nothing happens but the original works. I can't find my problem.

Additionally systemsound don't work either.

Any ideas?

Thank you!!

```
using System.Media;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;

namespace WpfRibbonApplication14
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
    {
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("sound.wav");

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            player.LoadAsync();

            // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
        }

        private void Button1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            player.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try turning up the volume.  Without an exception there isn't anything to diagnose.  You critically depend on Environment.CurrentDirectory to be set correctly, that isn't healthy.

Comment: That's the first thing that I did but it didn't work. Thanks for the hint concering the directory, but this is just to see if it works.

Comment: I don't know if that's of importance but setting a breakpoint on the player.play() line doesn't cause a break nothing happens. I'm at a loss

Comment: Focus on learning how to set a button's Click event handler.  Any WPF tutorial covers that.

Comment: Hi Hans!
I actually did it like this because the example that I downloaded did it like this also. Although I'm a beginner I know how to write a Click event. Listening to you now it works. hmmm ...  I'm just stupid or need a break of whatever ....
Thank you!

Comment: I think what Hans was trying to tell you is to check if your Button1_MouseLeftButtonDown was actually hooked up in the MainWindow.xaml to Button1's click event such as: <button Name="Button1" Click="Button1_MouseLeftButtonDown".

Comment: A few suggestions:
1) Check the .wav file is uncompressed - SoundPlayer is extremely limited in terms of what it can play - which is uncompressed .wav files only!
2) Try listening to the soundplayer LoadCompleted event. Stick a breakpoint in the handler - is it being hit? If so, it may be the case the button click event is being raised before the sound file is loaded.

Comment: @Hans Passant, it would be helpful to the community if you could copy your comment into an answer and if user774326 could mark this question as answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your `Button1_MouseLeftButtonDown` event handler was actually hooked up in your MainWindow.xaml to Button1's click event, e.g.: `<Button Name="Button1" Click="Button1_MouseLeftButtonDown" />`

*PS: I came here expecting this question to be unanswered, but it had actually been answered in the comments, so I'm reposting the answer here. I am not trying to steal [Hans Passant's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) rep, honest!*